# Disable all buttons for a amount of time after clicking one react native

Tags: react-native

So I have 16 buttons that are created by a function class. When I press a button I call a function but I also want to disable all buttons for a short amount of time.
At the moment only the button that I click gets disabled. How could I make it so that all buttons get disabled?

```
class ButtonGp extends Component{
  state = { isDisabled: false };

  disableButton(){
    this.setState({isDisabled: true});
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({isDisabled: false}), 5000);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.buttonGroup}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Button
              onPress={() => {sendData(this.props.value1); 
                              this.disableButton();}}
              color="#0f0"
              title="On"
              disabled= {this.state.isDisabled}
            />
            <Button
              onPress={() => {sendData(this.props.value2); 
                              this.disableButton();}}
              color="#f00"
              title="Off"
              disabled= {this.state.isDisabled}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  sendData = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    var url = `***********`;
    fetch(url);
  }

  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text style={styles.header}>Control panel</Text>
       <View>
        <View style={styles.buttonsCol}>
          <ButtonGp name="Relais 1" value1="000" value2="001" /> 
          <ButtonGp name="Relais 2" value1="010" value2="011" />
        </View>   
        <View style={styles.buttonsCol}>
          <ButtonGp name="Relais 3" value1="040" value2="041" />
          <ButtonGp name="Relais 4" value1="050" value2="051" />
        </View>    
        // This a few more times
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need one extra piece of state:

```
// Turn it on
setDisabled(true);
// Turn it off later
setTimeout(() => setDisabled(false), 5000);
```

Then send disabled into all the button components and use it to render their enabled state.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const sendData = (data) => {
    setDisabled(true);
    setTimeout(() => setDisabled(false), 5000);
  };

  return <>
    <Buttons onPress={sendData} disabled={disabled} />;
  </>;
};

const Buttons = ({disabled, onPress}) => {
  return <Button disabled={disabled} onPress={onPress} />;
};
```

Comment: I'm very new to react native, how can I update their enabled/disabled state from in the function disableButtons()?

Comment: Is there a possibility you could give more of an example? because I've tried a lot of things but they don't work out for me.

Comment: That's what props are. You are already sending props name, state1, and state2 in to your button component.

Comment: So in the meantime I've came up with a solution but it only disables the button that I click, I'll update my code in the question. Your answer is almost the same then my solution! Big thanks already!